# setting up hasOne relationship GeddyJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, geddy

I'm trying to expand on the GeddyJS Todo tutorial from their site. I've added another model, Project, to the Todo project, and would like to set up a relationship between Todo and Project in a Todo-hasOne-Project manner.

Here's the code from my create controller method where I attempt to set the relationship up after the Todo item is saved:

```
todo.save(function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            params.errors = err;
            self.transfer('add');
        } else {
            geddy.model.Project.getProjectById(todo.parent, function(err, project) {
                if(err) {
                    params.errors = err;
                    self.transfer('add');
                }
                else {
                    todo.setProject(project);
                    self.redirect({ controller: self.name });
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

I'm using a class method (getProjectById) that takes the todo's parent property (Project's id) to fetch the project from the db.

In my Todo class file, I have the hasOne relationship defined as follows:

```
this.hasOne('Project');
```

I keep getting compiler errors that read:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\geddy\node_modules\model\lib\index.js:254
            throw new Error('Item cannot have a hasOne/hasMany association ' +
                  ^
Error: Item cannot have a hasOne/hasMany association if it is not yet saved..
```

Finding by-example documentation has proven difficult, so I thought I'd ask the strongest community on the web.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you still experiencing this issue? If so can you try running

`$ npm update -g geddy`

This will most likely fix your issue.